# How do I write a conditional assignment in a Linux script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, conditional-statements

I need to create a formula in a Linux shell script.  If this was DOS, I'd (probably) be fine, but I've made the change and need to learn....!

D1 = a 5-digit number between 40500 and 49500 (this is atmospheric pressure data from an airport SYNOP report)

D2 = the last four digits of D1 (I can do that)

D3 = the first digit of D2 (I can do that as well)

D4 will be D2 divided by 10, to which 1000 is added only if D3=0.

I'm looking for something like: IF D3=0 THEN D4=((D2/10)+1000) ELSE D4=(D2/10)

Thanks,
Nigel.

Comment: The tools `sh`, `bash` and others, they are far harder to master than Microsoft batches. Start from here: [The GNU `bash` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've pretty much got it down already, and it's down only to minor syntax problems.

What you have, in pseudocode, is pretty much this:

```
if d3 equals 0 then
    set d4 equal to ((d2/10)+1000)
else
    set d4 equal to (d2/10)
end if
```

which translates to, in bash (which is what you'd be most likely to use for shell scripting in Linux):

```
if test "$d3" -eq "0"; then
    d4=$(( ( $d2 / 10 ) + 1000 ))
else
    d4=$(( $d2 / 10 ))
fi
```

You need the `fi` to end the `if` statement, and `$(( ... ))` is arithmetic expansion in bash. *Note that `$( ... )` is completely different;* that is *process substitution* which takes the output of the given command and returns it. Highly useful, but not really what you are after here.

The above assumes that `$d2`, `$d3` and `$d4` are already set to the correct values, and that there are no environment variables with conflicting names set.

If you know *for a fact* that `$d3` will never contain anything but digits you can do away with the quoting in the parameters to `test`, but I like to keep it in as a safety net. To learn more about what you can do with `test` (in bash), have a look at `man bash` under the *Shell builtin commands* heading. Other shells *may* use the external command, in which case `man test` applies (you can use the external command in bash e.g. through `if command test ...; then` if you prefer that for some reason).

The semicolon before the `then` is needed because `then` really is a separate command in bash; you could also put `then` on a separate line and omit the semicolon, which is another way of formatting exactly the same thing.

Comment: Michael, many thanks. In my code, D2 appears to assume the actual formula 'cut -c2-5 D1.txt' rather than the output of that formula.

Comment: In my script I have:
`D2='cut -c2-5 D1.txt'
$D2
# D3=first digit of D2
D3='cut -c2-2 D1.txt'
$D3
if test "$D3" -eq "0"; then
    D4=$(( ( $D2 / 10 ) + 1000 ))
else
    D4=$(( $D2 / 10 ))
fi
$D4`

The variables echo their correct values, but the `test` function fails with: /home/pi/update-pressure-db.sh: line 13: test: cut -c2-2 D1.txt: integer expression expected
/home/pi/update-pressure-db.sh: line 16: cut -c2-5 D1.txt / 10 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".txt / 10 ") 
It looks as though the value of D3 is literally `'cut -c2-2 D1.txt'` .  Help!

Comment: @user277524 You have `d3='cut -c2-2 D1.txt'` but want `d3=$(cut -c2-2 D1.txt)`. It's the difference between literal assignment and assignment of the output of process substitution. If that does not help, I strongly suggest that you ask a new question about that problem rather than posting in a comment.